# Получить дескриптор окна GLFW (#Окно без рамки)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, glfw

Всем привет
Делаю приложение с собственным интерфейсом, Но нигде нет инструкции как изменить стиль окна созданного с помощью glfw. По этому решил модифицировать окно через WinApi. Но так и не сумел получить дескриптор окна с помощью glfw. Сделал так чтобы получать дескриптор активного окна как только создано мое окно. Это работает рамку отключает, но в теории если в между созданием окна и применением свойства окна по какой то причине станет активным любое другое окно, то свойство применит к активному.

**Вопрос**, Как получить дескриптор при помощи GLFW. Чтоб на 100% это был дескриптор созданного мной окна. Нашол вот такую команду `glfwGetWin32Window(window)` но мне IDE пишет что такой команды не существует.

Вот код работоспособен, но не правильным способом.

***C++, visual studio 2010, glfw, WinApi.***

```
#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glfw3.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glew32s.lib")
#include <iostream>
// GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
// GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3native.h>

// GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include<Windows.h>



int main()
{
    // Init GLFW
    glfwInit();
    // Set all the required options for GLFW
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);


    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(700, 500, "OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);


    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    //HWND ds = FindWindow("Notepad", NULL); //Получит дескриптор пно названию возможно по классу?
    HWND ds = GetForegroundWindow(); //Получить дескриптор активного окна
    std::cout<<ds;

    //Сделать окно прозрачным
    /*SetWindowLong(ds, GWL_EXSTYLE,
        GetWindowLong(ds, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
    // Делаем окно на 70% не прозрачным
    ::SetLayeredWindowAttributes(ds, 0, (255 * 70) / 100, LWA_ALPHA);*/




    //HWND hWnd =  glfwGetWin32Window(window); Не работает Отсуцтвует команда




    SetWindowLongPtr(ds, GWL_STYLE, WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE); //Вимкнути рамки

    // HWND hWnd = GetForegroundWindow(); //Получить дескриптор активного окна





    // Game loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
        glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.7, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
    // Terminate GLFW, clearing any resources allocated by GLFW.
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам все это нужно, чтобы убрать рамку у окна?

Перед созданием окна делаете:

```cpp
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, false);
```

Comment: Капец, сколько вопросов по данной теме встречал, никто не ответил.  И не одного годного ответа не было. Спасибо вам.  Может вы ещё знаете, возможно ли и указать  TransparencyKey для окна glfw. Если нужно могу сделать отдельный вопрос

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка Про transparency key не знаю, но есть `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_TRANSPARENT_FRAMEBUFFER, true);`, позволяющая делать окно прозрачным/полупрозрачным в некоторых местах.

Comment: Спасибо получилось
Установил 
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_TRANSPARENT_FRAMEBUFFER, true);

И чёрный цвет стал прозрачным